# Find limit using definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

> Use the $\varepsilon -\delta$ definition of limit to show that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 1} (x^3+x+1)=3$

Here's my attempt:

When $|x-1|<\delta$ we have $$|x^3+x+1-3|=|x-1||x^2+x+2|<\delta |x^2+x+2|$$

Assuming $|x-1|<1$, we have that $-1<x-1<1$, which implies that $|x|<2$ and $|x^2|<4$.

Now, by the triangle inequality we get $|x^2+x+2|\leq |x^2|+|x|+|2|<4+2+2=8.$

Let $\delta =$min$\left(1,\frac{\varepsilon}{8}\right)$, then $$|x^3+x+1-3|<\delta|x^2+x+2|$$ $$<8\delta$$ $$\leq 8\frac{\varepsilon}{8}=\varepsilon$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is conceptually correct. For submission, I would recommend moving the definition of $\delta$ to the beginning.